# CoreData One-To-Many, sorting the many

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a small app that I'm working on to learn CoreData.  These are the entities for CoreData.

```
extension Person {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var age: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var personToBook: NSSet?

}

extension Books {

    @NSManaged var bookName: String?
    @NSManaged var bookISBN: String?
    @NSManaged var bookToPerson: Person?

}
```

The app is a list of people.  Belonging to each person in the list can be one more more books.

I am easily able to sort the people.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    let fetchSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [fetchSort]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unable to perform fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

What I am having a tough time working out is how to sort the Books in alphabetical order, like I am the people.  When I tap on a person in the people list, I segue to a `UITableView` that contains a list of books.  In the prepareForSegue, I pass in the selected person, the context, and the `NSFetchedResultsController` that I am using in the person list.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! BooksController

    vc.person = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(selectedIndex) as! Person
    vc.context = self.context
    vc.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController
}
```

The `UITableView` is populated by person.personToBook.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (person.personToBook?.count)!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BooksCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let book = person.personToBook?.allObjects[indexPath.row] as! Books

    cell.textLabel?.text = book.bookName!

    return cell
}
```

Books are added to the correct person in this manner:

```
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Books", inManagedObjectContext: self.context)
            let bookInstance = Books(entity:entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)

            bookInstance.bookName = alertController.textFields?[0].text
            bookInstance.bookISBN = alertController.textFields?[1].text

            self.person.mutableSetValueForKey("personToBook").addObject(bookInstance)

            do {
                try self.context.save()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error saving a book \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
```

personToBook is an NSSet, and this is not sorted.  I thought about using another `NSFetchedResultsController to pull the list of books out, but there is nothing unique that is identifying the books as belonging to a specific user.  For instance, I could have two people with the same name of John Doe.  Because of this, I'd have no way to set the`NSPredicate` so that it would only pull in books for one of the John Does.

One though that I had is that I could add some sort of UniqueID to the Person entity, like I'd do in SQL.  This would ensure that I could get the Books records for only the correct person.  I've been told that I should not do this in CoreData.  That leads me to believe that there must be some way to sort the items in the to-many part of this.

What are the ways that I can sort my Books data?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `NSSortDescriptor` on your `UITableView`? (preferable when setting the `fetchedResultsController`)

Comment: I am setting NSSortDescriptor on the Person entity, as that's what I am doing the fetch on.  I am not doing the fetch on Books.  How can I set the NSSortDescriptor on Books, when I am only getting Books as a result of the fetch on Person?

Comment: What about this: Create one more `sortDescriptor` and add it to the array `let bookNameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "book.bookname", ascending: true)` -> `fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [fetchSort, bookNameSort]`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An NSSet is unordered.  The set won't return the books in the same order that you added them.

Here are three different approaches you could use for the books to be in alphabetical order.

1. Change the model's to-many `personToBook` to an ordered relationship.  This will use an `NSOrderedSet` instead of an `NSSet`.  Add the books to the ordered set in alphabetical order. (Note one disadvantage of this approach is that iCloud Core Data synchronisation does not support ordered relationships.)
2. Convert the NSSet of books to an array and sort that array.

   ```
   person.personToBook?.allObjects.sort({ $0.bookName < $1.bookName })
   ```
3. Use a Book fetchedResultsController to fetch and order a person's books.  Add a predicate specifying the person entity, so only the books for that person are returned.  Since you're comparing against an entity, not a name, it wouldn't matter if there is more than one author with that name.

   ```
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "bookToPerson", person)
   ```

As an aside, if an entity's attributes or relationships are not optional, those `@NSManaged` properties wouldn't need to be optional.  This would save you from having to unwrap values that would never be nil.  You can also specify the type of object in the set, so Swift knows that it's dealing with a Book, instead of an AnyObject.

```
    @NSManaged var personToBook: Set<Book> // Convention would be Book, not Books
```

You also can avoid passing the context or fetchedResultsController (of people).  You've passed a `Person` managed object which has a `managedObjectContext` property, and you're directly accessing the person's to-many Book relationship to get their books.  The Book view controller has no need to know about any other people that a master view controller happened to fetch.

Comment: I went with option #3, and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for taking the time to post this, and thanks for the other suggestions.

Comment: option #1 was just brilliant, just one click of a button and it worked ! Is there is a downside to it at all aside from the icloud synchronization? It just seemed too easy